# Registration form/Auto fill list - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I'm working with SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint designer 2013. I DON'T HAVE INFOPATH.

I have 2 lists, one is a training calendar and the other one is for registration to these training. Here's the picture.

[image: Two pictures in one]

As you can see on the first picture there's a link call "Register" on the calendar list. (I have a link that explain how to do so, but I need 10 reputation to put more than 2 links so too bad!) This link open a new form of the list "Mes cours" (it's the same list as "Inscription" in the second picture).

The first thing I want is that when I click on the "Register" link, the information of the row appear automatically. If someone click on the link towards Formation SharePoint, all the information about this class is on the form.

This way, when the employee click to register to a class, all the information about this class appear on the form. In the second picture I linked, I'd like that the "Title" (or meeting), "Start time", "End time", "Éligibilité", "Lieu", "Salle/Code connexion", "Nom du formateur" and "Langue" field appear on the form.

One important thing is that theses need to be read only, so employees can't change the information.

Here is the picture of what I want at the end if I click on the link Register towards "Formation SharePoint"

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1):

Not so trivial after all. I played around a bit and here is what I came up with:

Notes first:

1. You will need jQuery (at least on the *DispForm.aspx* of the *Training Calendar* list and on the *NewForm.aspx* of the Registration list)
2. You *Registration* list needs a lookup column to the *Training Calendar* list
3. You will have to deactivate *Minimal Download Stratgy* on the site, otherwise the scripts might not run

### Steps

**1. Your column *Register* will be empty by default. Add the following
    CSR to the view:**

```
Type.registerNamespace('SPOODOO')
SPOODOO.Demos = SPOODOO.Demos || {};
SPOODOO.Demos.Templates = SPOODOO.Demos.Templates || {}
SPOODOO.Demos.Functions = SPOODOO.Demos.Functions || {}

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.DisplayRegisterLink = function (ctx) {
    return "<a href='/Lists/Registration/NewForm.aspx?event=" + ctx.CurrentItem["ID"] + "'>Register</a>"
}

SPOODOO.Demos.Templates.Fields = {
    'Register': {
        'View': SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.DisplayRegisterLink
    }
}

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField = function () {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(SPOODOO.Demos)
}

SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.MdsRegisterField = function () {
    var thisUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "Style Library/register.js";
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField();
    RegisterModuleInit(thisUrl, SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField)
}

if (typeof _spPageContextInfo != "undefined" && _spPageContextInfo != null) {
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.MdsRegisterField()
} else {
    SPOODOO.Demos.Functions.RegisterField()
}
```

Sorry about all the SPOODOOs, you can change them to whatever Namespace you prefer. In order to add the CSR, put all that code in a *.js-file. Upload it to somewhere (Style Library for example). Then change the JSLINK-property of the view to something like:

```
~SiteCollection/Style Library/CSR.js
```

In the code you will find two URLs. You will have to change them to the proper paths. The upper one is the relative path to the registration list (change */Lists/Registration/NewForm.aspx* to the proper URL), the lower one to the relative path to the CSR file without the leading '/'.

Here you can find more CSR related information:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

**2. Modify the *DispForm.aspx* of your *Training Calendar* list**

Open any existing item and then *Edit the Page*. Add a *Script Editor Webpart* and add the following code:

```
<script>
    JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 
    var custom = JSRequest.QueryString["custom"];
    if(typeof custom != "undefined"){
        jQuery("#s4-ribbonrow").hide()
        jQuery("#part1 > *:last-child()").hide()
        jQuery("#pageTitle").hide()
    }
</script>
```

This should be the result:
[image]

Save the page and continue with step 3

**3. Modify the *NewForm.aspx* of your Registration list**

Click *New Item* on the Registration list, then edit the page.
Add a *Page Viewer Webpart* and define the URL as the URL of the *DispForm.aspx* of your *Training Calendar* list. Add *?ID=0* to it. It should look like that:

```
/Lists/TrainingCalendar/DispForm.aspx?ID=0
```

Now add another *Script Editor Webpart* and add the following code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 
        var eventId = JSRequest.QueryString["event"];
        var eventLookUpField = jQuery("[id^=Event_][id$='_$LookupField']")
        var eventIFrame = jQuery("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ3")
        if(typeof eventId != "undefined"){
            eventLookUpField.val(eventId)
            eventLookUpField.closest("tr").hide()
            eventIFrame.attr("src","/Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?isDlg=1&custom=1&ID=" + eventId)
        } else {
            eventLookUpField.on("change", function(e){
                eventId = eventLookUpField.val()
                eventIFrame.attr("src","/Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?isDlg=1&custom=1&ID=" + eventId)
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

Here ,again, you might have to change the URLs so that point to your *Training Calendar* list. You will also have to replace *Event* in this line to whatever the name of your lookup column is:

```
var eventLookUpField = jQuery("[id^=Event_][id$='_$LookupField']")
```

And this line might need a change as well:

```
jQuery("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ3")
```

Depending on the order you choose to add the webparts, the number at the end could be different (2, 3, 4). You can figure that out with your browsers Dev-tools.

And that's the result:
[image]

Save the page and you should have your expected result.

### Few example shots

The *Training Calendar* list  (called *Events* in my case):

[image]

The Registration-list *NewForm.aspx* when the normal *New Item* button was used and an event has been selected from the drop down (in that case the Event-selection drop down menu is visible):

[image]

The Registration-list *NewForm.aspx* when the *Register* button was used (in that case the Event-selection drop down is invisible):

[image]

Comment: How do I deactivate Minimal Download Strategy? I found that I have to write EnableMinimalDownload=False in the code. But I don't know where? In the home page code, list code? There are more than 200 lines, I never know where I have to put the code.

Comment: Also, in step 1 "Add the following CSR to the view", what does that mean? I know is basic but I don't know how to put a code in a *.js-file.

Comment: Disable MDN: _Site Settings_ >> _Site Features_ >> Search for _Minimal Download Strategy_ and click _Deactivate_. Create a text file, copy the code inside. rename the text file from .txt to .js.